# Как на LinuxMint 18.3 подключить менеджер программ от Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, repository

В установленном Linux Mint 18.3 имеется **Software manager** Каким образом можно расширить его возможности? Путём подключения репозиториев? Куда копать?

Comment: если под «менеджер программ от ubuntu» вы подразумеваете «центр приложений ubuntu», то «[Разработка была завершена в 2015 году и в Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Центр приложений был заменён на версию от GNOME](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_Ubuntu)». ежели на ubuntu версии 16.04 и выше (ваш дистрибутив также к ним относится) даже скачать нужные пакеты и установить, то [программа и запуститься не сможет](http://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=281678.0).

Answer (score 2):

В Mint описания репозиториев находятся в каталоге `/etc/apt`.

Из гуя можно воспользоваться штатной утилитой (Система -> Менеджер обновлений, там "Правка / Источники приложений"):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну или есть `add-apt-repository`, пример:

```
# Добавили репозиторий:
$ sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://debian.drdteam.org/ stable multiverse'
# Установили ключ:
$ wget -O - http://debian.drdteam.org/drdteam.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
# Обновились:
$ sudo apt-get update
# И устанавливаем любимую игрушку :)
$ sudo apt-get install zandronum doomseeker-zandronum
```